# Java POI - Read all numeric values in a Column

Tags: java, excel, file, arraylist, apache-poi

I am trying to get all numeric values(Integer) in a column of xlsx file worksheet. All the numeric values are available in text cell and there are no columns names.

I have tried with below code but I am not able to get the expected result since it is displayed some numeric values which are not available in the worksheet itself.

**Data in Column B**

```
qeweqwqe
Acc#
1212121
aaffssd
ACC#
20930293
9000sds
67623283309089789
Acc#
90909093
```

Java Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadWriteExcel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        extractExcelContentByColumnIndex(1);
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> extractExcelContentByColumnIndex(
            int columnIndex) {
        ArrayList<String> columndata = null;
        try {
            File f = new File("path/Sample.xlsx");
            FileInputStream ios = new FileInputStream(f);
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(ios);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            columndata = new ArrayList<>();

            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    if (row.getRowNum() > 0) { // To filter column headings
                        if (cell.getColumnIndex() == columnIndex) {// To match
                                                                    // column
                                                                    // index
                            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                columndata.add(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "");
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                cell.setCellType(cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                                columndata.add(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ios.close();
            System.out.println(columndata);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return columndata;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the `cell.setCellType(cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);` after checking that the cell's `cellType` is `Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING`? What do you expect to be the numeric value of `qeweqwqe`or `9000sds`? Please add a screen shot of your Excel sheet containing the data in column B.

Comment: Instead of looping on cellIterator and then checking index, you can directly get cell using row.getCell(1) . 1 is index of column 'B'.